# the user can reset his forgotten password

Tags: php

i made a php file that upon the user request sends him a link to restore his forgotten password the website sends him an email containing a token then he is redirected to a page to restore his password after the user puts his new password and repeats it correctly he presses the submit button my problem is when i press submit the php file forgets the token and return t me an error token not recognized.

---------forgotten password code:------------

```
<?php
include('./classes/DB.php');

if(isset($_POST['Resetpassword'])){

        /*bass 7otta live server besta3mil php mail */
        /*bi ma2anno ana bi local server ra7 esta3mil el token ka mail */
            $cstrong = True;
            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))[0]['id'];
            DB::query('INSERT INTO password_tokens VALUES (null, :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));

            echo 'email sent';

}


?>
<h1>Forgot Password</h1>
<form action="forgot_password.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email ...." required></p>
        <input type="submit" name="Resetpassword" value="Reset Password"></p>
</form>
```

---------restore password page:---------------

```
<?php
$style= "required";
include('./classes/DB.php');
include('./classes/Login.php');

if (Login::isLoggedIn()) {
        echo 'is logged in';
        if (isset($_POST['changepassword'])){

            $oldpassword = $_POST['oldpassword'];
            $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
            $newpasswordrepeat = $_POST['newpasswordrepeat'];
            $userid = Login::isLoggedIn();

            if (password_verify($oldpassword, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))[0]['password'])) {

                if($newpassword == $newpasswordrepeat){

                if (strlen($newpassword) >= 6 && strlen($newpassword) <= 60) {

                    DB::query('UPDATE users SET password =:newpassword WHERE id=:userid', array(':newpassword'=>password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':userid'=>$userid));
                    echo 'password changed succesfuly';

                }

                }else{
                    echo 'password don\'t match';
                }

            }else{
                echo 'incorrect old password';
            }
        }
} 
else {
    $link= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $link_array = explode ('/' ,$link);
     $token = end($link_array);
    IF(DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM password_tokens where token=:token', array (':token'=>$token))[0]['user_id']){

            $user_id = DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM password_tokens where token=:token', array (':token'=>$token))[0]['user_id'];
            echo $user_id;


                $style= "style= 'display:none'";

        if (isset($_POST['changepassword'])){

            $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
            $newpasswordrepeat = $_POST['newpasswordrepeat'];

                if($newpassword == $newpasswordrepeat){

                if (strlen($newpassword) >= 6 && strlen($newpassword) <= 60) {


                    DB::query('UPDATE users SET password =:newpassword WHERE id=:userid', array(':newpassword'=>password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':userid'=>$user_id));
                }

                }else{
                    echo 'password don\'t match';

                }


    }
    }
    else {
        die ('token invalid');
    }

        }       
?>

<h1>change your password</h1>
<form action="change_password.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="oldpassword" value="" placeholder="Current password" <?php echo $style;?>></p>
<input type="password" name="newpassword" value="" placeholder="New password ..." required></p>
<input type="password" name="newpasswordrepeat" value="" placeholder="repeat password ..." required></p>
<input type="button" name="changepassword" value="change password">
</form>
```

Comment: Could be related to the posting here, but proper indentation would help greatly.  In the "restore password page", the form as the action defined to change_password.php.  Are they the same page?  What is the filename to "restore password page"?

Comment: If I assume that change_password.php is your "restore password page", when you press submit, $_POST will have oldpassword, newpassword, newpasswordrepeat.  But you get your token from the link.  When clicking submit, the link is just change_password.php.  You need to add the token as in input field in the form if you want it to come back in the $_POST (input type="hidden").  Clicking the submit will not build the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with the token into it.  Then modify your code to get the $token from the $_POST if there, form the link otherwise.

Comment: the restore password page is called change_password this page has 2 output the first output is when the user want to change his password and the second output is when the user had forgotten his password and he access the page using the token sent to his email

Comment: So... solved or just thanking "us" for the answer so far?  :-)

Comment: i got your idea i am working on it :) i am thanking you for helping me ❤️